# Android app: What is running in background?

Tags: android, backgroundworker, kill-process

I have almost finished developing an Android App. I use the GPS location and sms receiver class. I can see that if I press "HOME"(the house), it's still running. I would like to close the GPS listener and the SMS_RECEIVER when home button is pressed.

I am using eclipse and windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen the onStop Events and shutdown the listeners.

[Activity.onStop documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onStop%28%29)

Note: maybe onPause or onDestroy might be better options. Read [activity life-cycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#Lifecycle) and choose the best point to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Using the home button to exit will leave your app running (home, from what I understand, is more of a "minimize" button). Use back to close completely. To override the home button functionality to actually exit, use this:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME:
            finish();
            return true;
        }
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: Jack is correct but it is highly discouraged to override the Home keys default action

Comment: Yes Spidy is right - you generally want to conform to the Android guidelines and not do this, BUT the option is available. Think of the home button keeping your app running more as a feature, rather than a problem :P. What you could do is override the onPause() (or onStop) method to stop your locationservices and sms receiver, and then override onResume() to re-instantiate them

Answer (score 0):

If you use BroadCast receivers(you probably use separate classes and declare receivers in AndroidManifest.xml) then consider making them class members of your Activity. Inside Activity class override onResume and onPause and register and unregister receivers there.

Comment: I do not have BroadCast in a seperate class.